# Windows 7 and Ubuntu work together

Tags: boot

I used to have in my laptop two OS: Windows 7 and Ubuntu, and I was able to choose from  them what would I use when I booted the laptop. Now I have re-installed Windows 7 but after I finished the installation I found that I could not choose anymore the OS at the boot time, and Windows 7 would boot directly. I want to be able to choose the system a last time. Do anybody know what I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

boot-repair should help you out. Just boot ubuntu out of a LiveCD, do not install it bust just "try it out", and install boot-repair (explained here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Click on recommended repair, and that's it!

Comment: i think advanced settings works better because i don't like waiting for 10sec for boot menu, although you can select your preffered os from advenced setting

Comment: @biozalp: Yes, but that'll make the procedure more complicated and (user) error prone. It's better to keep it simple and tweak the minor settings once things are working again.